# php-fpm8.4 and nginx .php file downloaded instead of opened in browser

Tags: php, docker, nginx

I'm pretty new to docker and it's for a school assignment.

I have 3 debian:bookworm docker containers running:

- mariadb
- wordpress + php8.3
- nginx

﻿My nginx.conf file

```
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; 
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

    types {
        application/x-httpd-php               php;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name agunczer.42.fr;
        root /var/www/html;
        index index.php;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            # try_files $uri =404;
            # include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            # fastcgi_pass wordpress:9000;
            proxy_pass http://wordpress:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
}
```

My www.conf

```
[www]
user = www-data
group = www-data
listen = 0.0.0.0:9000
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 5
pm.start_servers = 2
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 3
chdir = /
php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/php8.3-fpm.log
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
php_admin_value[upload_max_filesize] = 100M
php_admin_value[post_max_size] = 100M
security.limit_extensions = .php .php3 .php4 .php5 .php7 .php8
```

Link to the full project: https://github.com/AndorGunczer/42-Inception

What I've tried so far:

- Accessing html files work fine
- Network connection is fine, the containers are pingable
- Services are running and are listening on the appropriate port

I know everything runs in root at the moment, please abstain from security related comments, this is my first docker project, I just want to get things working before moving onto that aspect.